# How to limit the data fired on the first load using Table Pagination MUI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have question how can I limit the data on the first fire of the page? Right now I experience when I set the count property of table to = 1 the data table still on same limit. I used MUI for the data table.

Version: "@mui/material": "^5.0.0",

**Goal:** limit the data on the first load of the page to = 10

Here is the table structure:

```
    <TableContainer sx={{ maxHeight: 440, mt:4 }}>

    <Table>
        <TableHead sx={{backgroundColor:'#F9F9F9'}}>
            <TableRow>
            {columns.map((column) => (
                <TableCell
                    key={column.id}
                    align={column.align}
                    style={{ top: 57, minWidth: column.minWidth, fontWeight:'bold' }}
                >
                {column.label}
                </TableCell>
            ))}
            </TableRow>
        </TableHead>
        <TableBody>
            {userList?.map((row) => (
                <TableRow key={row.id}>
                    <TableCell>
                        {row.name}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        {row.email}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        {row.role != '' && null ? row.role : '-'}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                        {row.status}
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell >
                        <Visibility onClick={handleOpenEditUser} style={{color:'#3167E9'}}/>
                        <Delete style={{color:'#F53C56'}}/>
                    </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
            ))}
        </TableBody>
    </Table>
</TableContainer>

<TablePagination
    rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
    component="div"
    count={1}
    rowsPerPage={1}
    page={1}
    onChangePage={handleChangePage}
    onChangeRowsPerPage={handleChangeRowsPerPage}
/>
```

[image: Sample Output]

Comment: You didn't mean _@mui/icons-material_ but _@mui/material_, right? We need to see your handle functions also. It doesn't work by itself. You have to write some logic. There is [fully working example with pagination in documentation](https://mui.com/components/tables/#sorting-amp-selecting).

Comment: yes sorry , I will correct the import content.